# How to choose which internal precision of float32 matrix multiplications to use in PyTorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, floating-point, gpu

PyTorch 1.12 [changed the default fp32 math to be "highest precision"](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/76509), and introduced the [torch.set_float32_matmul_precision API](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.set_float32_matmul_precision.html#torch-set-float32-matmul-precision), allowing users to specify which precision out of `medium`, `high` and `highest` to use for the internal precision of float32 matrix multiplications.

From the documentation, I read that choosing a lower precision "may significantly increase performance, and in some programs the loss of precision has a negligible impact".

**1. How do I determine whether my program would benefit from setting a lower precision? Is this purely empirical?**

Similarly, when training with [PyTorch Lightning](https://www.pytorchlightning.ai/index.html), I get the following warning:

```
You are using a CUDA device ('NVIDIA A100-SXM4-40GB') that has Tensor Cores. To properly utilize them, you should set `torch.set_float32_matmul_precision('medium' | 'high')`
```

This seems to answer 1. (i.e., when your GPU has tensor cores, use a lower precision), but doesn't suggest which of the two lower precisions to use.

**2. How do you determine which of the lower precisions ("high" or "medium") to use? Is *this* purely empirical? What's the suggested approach?**

Comment: Predicting how precision affects quality is hard. AFAICT most people determine it empirically. If the model works *well enough* in lower precision, great. If it does't, use higher precision or fix the model.